# Adding subdomain to NGinX programmatically

Tags: php, shell, nginx, subdomain, command-line-interface

## IDEA

What I want to do is to give subdomain ability to users. Like

**username**.domain.com

## Technical part

As far as I know technically to get this job done I have to do following steps:

1. **DNS part:** Add dns record *.domain.com which wildcard forwards all incoming traffic to server's IP
2. **Nginx Part:** To create template configuration file using variables inside. Every time when you create new subdomain to copy and change variables inside this file.
3. **Shell part:** to create executable shell file to change variables inside template file, copy and restart nginx server.
4. **PHP Part:** to fire shell script using php.

## Problem

Now 1st step already done. I'm not sure about 2nd and 3rd. Maybe there is ready to use methods or some debian package that already does it on the fly. Any suggestions? or maybe someone has better solution to get this job done?

Comment: Might be more on-topic on http://serverfault.com/